# Prove that $2002^{2001}$ and $2002^{2001}+2^{2001}$ have the same number of digits.

Tags: arithmetic

I have an arithmetic exercise as follows: Prove that $2002^{2001}$ and $2002^{2001}+2^{2001}$ have a same number of digits. It seems easy but I don't know how to do. I can do it if $2002$ is replaced by $2000$. Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add your way through the problem if $2002$ is replaced by $2000$?

Comment: Yes, let say $2^{2001}=A$, then $2000^{2001}=A.10^{2001}$, so $2^{2001}+2000^{2001}=A+\bar{A0...0}=\bar{A0...0A}$.

Comment: If $2^{2001}=A$, then $2000^{2001}=A\times 10^{3\times 2001}$

Comment: And $A<10^{2001}$ which has 2002 digits.

Answer (score 1):

For those who learned key facts about logarithms in their youth, here is a way through which may not appeal to OP (though if decent log tables to five digits are available this will do - I did it using facts I remember).

The first number is $$M=2^{2001}\cdot1001^{2001}$$

The second is $$N=2^{2001}\cdot\left(1001^{2001}+1\right)$$

Now if we take logs to base $10$ $$\log M=2001 \log 2+2001 (3+\log 1.001)$$

We want to estimate the leading digit (or few) of $M$ and hence the decimal part of the logarithm to a significant figure or two.

Now $\log 2 =0.30103$ to the nearest $0.00001$ so $2001 \log 2$ is within the bounds $602.36\pm 0.02$

$\ln 10 \approx 2.303$ (within 0.05%) and $\ln 1.001 \approx 0.001$ (easily within 0.5%) so $\log 1.001 =\cfrac {\ln 1.001}{\ln 10} \approx 0.00043$ and $2001 \log 1.001 \approx 0.86$ certainly to within $2\%$ so say $\pm 0.02$

So the fractional part of the logarithm is $0.86+0.36\pm0.04=1+0.22\pm 0.04$ which makes the leading digit $1$.

If the leading digit is $1$, then increasing the number by less than 1% will not increase the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the number of digits in a decimal number N is given by $\lfloor{\log_{10}N}\rfloor + 1$

They key is to find an estimate for the base-10 logarithm of the number.

Start with the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and convert that to a base-10 log.

Then try to figure out how to use that to compute a series for $\log_{10}(2002^{2001} + 2^{2001})$

Now see if you can manipulate that into proving that the result is very close to $\log_{10}2002^{2001}$. More precisely, you want to prove that the floor of the base-10 log of one number is equal to the floor of the base-10 log of the other.

Comment: Well, what you want is an estimate of the floor (I don't know how to represent the floor function in Latex) of the result plus 1, which will give you the number of digits.

Comment: Btw, can we limit the knowledge for only highschool students? I don't know anything about Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Deepak, just add the floor word to your answer wherever required. I'll convert it to latex...

Comment: @Apurv. No worries, looked it up. Thanks for the offer. :)

Comment: Could the person downvoting me please tell me why? Is my approach wrong? Or is it just that it's not optimal?

Comment: @Deepak, i'll convert that to an upvote

Comment: @Apurv, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2002^{2001} \gt 2^{2001}\cdot 1000^{2001}$, so there will not be a carry unless $2002^{2001}$ starts with over $6000\ \ 9$'s.  $\log_{10} {2002}^{2001}=2001\log 2002\approx 2001\cdot (3.30103+\log_{10} 1.001)$ and the decimal part is *far* from $0.9999$

Answer (score -1):

$\ln (a + b) = \ln (a(1 + \dfrac{b}{a})) = \ln a + \ln (1 + \dfrac{b}{a})$.

The number of digits in the base-10 numeral for integer $n > 0$ is $\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil$.  $\log_{10} n = \dfrac{\ln n}{\ln 10}$

Let $a = 2002^{2001}$ and $b = 2^{2001}$

$\lceil \log_{10} a \rceil = \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln a}{\ln 10} \right\rceil = \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln 2002^{2001}}{\ln 10} \right\rceil=\left\lceil \dfrac{2001 \ln 2002}{\ln 10} \right\rceil = \lceil 6606.2296\dots\rceil = 6697$

$$\begin{align}
\\ \lceil \log_{10} (a + b)\rceil &= \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln (a+ b)}{\ln 10} \right\rceil 
\\ & =  \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln a + \ln (1 + \dfrac{b}{a})}{\ln 10} \right\rceil 
\\ & =  \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln a + \ln \left(1 + \left(\dfrac{2}{2002}\right)^{2001}\right)}{\ln 10} \right\rceil 
\\ & =  \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln a + O(10^{-6003})}{\ln 10} \right\rceil 
\\ & =  \left\lceil \dfrac{\ln a}{\ln 10} + O(10^{-6003}) \right\rceil
\\ & =  \left\lceil 6606.2296\dots + O(10^{-6003}) \right\rceil
\\ &= 6697
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your answer is largely similar to mine, but note that what you wrote is not entirely correct. $\lceil{\log_{10}1}\rceil = 0$, but it has 1 digit. This is why I used $\lfloor{\log_{10}N}\rfloor + 1$ in my answer. There are also typos. $\lceil{6606.2296...}\rceil = 6607$, not $6697$ as you wrote.